# Google Chrome GPO/GPM (ADMX) allow themes only + whitelisted extensions installation

Tags: google-chrome, active-directory, group-policy

In Windows domain (AD -> GPM), I've been playing around with [Google Chrome ADMX](https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip) to achieve both the following:

1. users can install any template (visual, look)
2. users cannot install any extension except for those whitelisted

I am not successful :(

I can achieve either of those separately, but not **combined together**. Any hints? Many thanks!

Comment: Why can't you? Error message? One blocks the other?

Comment: Because it forces me to use the whitelist policy (valid for both themes and plugins), whereas I want to allow ALL themes and only whitelist plugins.